# Why was this question voted as too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367677/converting-the-harfbuzz-library-from-c-to-c-sharp) question and was greeted by an immediate "too broad" response.

How is this question too broad? As part of due diligence I found that a related issue did involve a tool, and included that in the question. One of the commenters asked if I'm specifically asking for a tool. No, it is a "how" question, any approach is fine. If the answer involves a tool, so be it.

Aren't such questions well within the scope of StackOverflow?

Comment: The place to ask would be meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: [Is “How do I convert code from this language to this language” too broad?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296126/839601)

Answer (score 9):

> Aren't such questions well within the scope of StackOverflow?

No. How to do a big, giant task like converting an entire library from one language to another is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. It is very much "too broad".

> So asking about a giant task like converting from C++ to assembly is also "too broad"?

No, that would be closed for asking for a tool.

> I've clearly stated I want an approach, not for someone to solve the problem.

And how many possible approaches are there for doing something as complex as porting a library between languages? Lots of them. It's too broad of a task for SO.

Comment: So asking about a giant task like converting from C++ to assembly is also "too broad"? The answer is to use a compiler. I've clearly stated I want an approach, not for someone to solve the problem. Sorry but I don't get it. Programming is *all about* converting one giant thing to another. Using the word *giant* does not make it too broad.

Comment: @bright: See added text.

Comment: *sigh* there are countless convert-this-*giant*-thing-to-that programming questions on stackoverflow. Again, I'm asking "how", not for a tool. An answer that involves a tool is fine.

Comment: @bright: "*there are countless convert-this-giant-thing-to-that programming questions on stackoverflow*" Where?

Comment: Just because others exist doesn't mean that they actually should.